# ASP.NET Core with Angular 2 (cli init) doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, angular

I`m do creating **Empty** ASP.NET Core project. In folder **wwwroot** i run **ng init** via cmd. After restoring packages i host my ASP project on **Kestrel**. Compiler output project compile-time errors
Errors in files of *.aspx.cs in the wwwroot\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\test\data folder.

How to delete this [protractor, selenium, webdriver] what there would be no errors any more *OR/AND* to deliver restriction to the compiler on the wwwroot folder?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Webdriver doesn't work with ASP.NET Core. Try using this sample:

**package.json**

```
{
"name": "angular",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "Angular 2, ASP.NET Core, Visual Studio 2017 RC",
"scripts": {
"postinstall": "gulp restore"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "~2.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~2.2.0",
"@angular/core": "~2.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "~2.2.0",
"@angular/http": "~2.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~2.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.2.0",
"@angular/router": "~3.2.0",

"angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.2.4",
"systemjs": "0.19.41",
"core-js": "2.4.1",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.9",
"rxjs": "5.0.3",
"zone.js": "0.7.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
"typescript": "^2.1.4",
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"@types/node": "^6.0.46",
"@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36"
},
"repository": {}
}
```